# Which one should I choose to install on my server: Windows 2003 Standard or Windows 2008 Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008, dedicated-hosting

I'm in the process of looking for a dedicated server to host my soon to be released web apps. THey are build with ASP.NEt and uses Sql Server 2005. I've got a great deal with a company for a Intel Core2Quad Q9300 with 8Gb or ram and 750Gb sata.

They offer me Windows 2003 64 Standard or Windows 2008 64 Web for free, which one should I choose?

My main concern is about the database, in the first moment I'm going to have only one box to host both the web and database layer. Will I be able to install SQL Server (initially the express edition, then eventually the standard) on the Web version of Windows 2008?

Comment: The title and contents of your message do not match, regarding 2003 vs 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get Server 2008, i'd go with it because IIS7 is an excellent Upgrade to IIS6.

SQL Server **Standard** 2008 64-Bit is officially supported on Windows 2008 Web Server. SQL Server **Enterprise** 2008 64-Bit is NOT (not sure if it does work and is only not listed. 32-Bit Enterprise is listed, but running 32-Bit on a modern server does not sound appealing). See [System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SEx64) here for a full list of SQL Server 2008 Editions and supported Servers.

Not sure about SQL Server 2005, there seems to be [a patch](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/04/15/windows-web-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005.aspx) needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can run SQL Server on Server 2008 Web Edition (this is a change from Server 2003 Web Edition). The main limitations I am aware of between Web and Standard for 2008 is Web cannot do any kind of virtualization, Active Directory or DNS management, etc. It is intended to be essentially an application server.

I would recommend the newer OS, since it comes with IIS7 and the enhanced TCP/IP (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

If its free, go for the standard version. Here is a comparison of the features:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-features.aspx

I've never noticed any performance differences in the versions, so might as well get features you might use someday. Expensive to upgrade later.

You can run the SQL on either one.

Comment: I think he is trying to compare 2003 Standard to 2008 Web, judging from the text of the question. I would recommend the newer OS, since it comes with IIS7 and the enhanced TCP/IP (among other things)

Comment: Actually, you are right, his question is inconsistent title to body and I assumed he was comparing the 2008 versions, if it is 2003 standard versus 2008 web, I'd also go for the 2008 web version.